# How to pass arguments to a PyQT5 button function?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qt5, pyqt5

I am new to QT, and I am having difficulty using a function that has arguments in a QT-designer generated GUI. How do you tie a button to a function that has arguments? I can get the button to work with a print "hello world" function. Functions with arguments result in a boolean "False" when I click the button.

```
import GUITESTFUNCS    
self.pushButton.clicked.connect(GUITESTFUNCS.display)
```

The function I import for my GUI button to use is...

```
#practice functions for GUITEST

a = 8

def display(a):
    print(str(a))
```

Comment: You should read about the underlying signal&slot mechanisms before you start messing with them: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html. Thus http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you connect a signal to a function, any arguments passed to the function are generated by the signal that is emitted, not some arbitrary value that you define elsewhere in your code. You can look up the `clicked` signal in the [QT docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#clicked) and see that the argument for that signal is a boolean that is only relevant if the button is checkable. In your case, the button is either not checkable or isn't checked, that is why you're getting `False` as the parameter to your `display` function.

If you want to connect a signal to a function and for that function to receive a parameter that the signal doesn't generate, I usually do that like this:

```
from functools import partial

def display(arg):
    print(arg)

a = 8

display_a = partial(display, a)

self.pushButton.clicked.connect(display_a)
```